# ho to check size of image from fileupload and how to check whether selected file is image

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

im my web page having file upload option..it has to check two conditions.
1)whether the selected item is image or not..if image means then only it allow user to excute otherwise wont.
2)check selected image size (it allow limited size only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can make it simple using RegularExpressionValidator

   ```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadFile" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="UpLoadValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Upload Images only." ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.png|.bmp|.jpeg|.gif)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
   ```
2. Set image maximum size in web.config

   ```
   <system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288"/>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

Comment: how to fix the size for that image?because allow user to upload image in our size only

Answer (score 0):

To tell whether file is an image just look at the extension (System.File.Path.GetExtension). You can easily resize image and make sure it doesnt exceed certain size:

```
public static Bitmap CreateThumbnail(Bitmap loBMP, int lnWidth, int lnHeight)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmpOut = null;
    try
    {
        ImageFormat loFormat = loBMP.RawFormat;

        decimal lnRatio;
        int lnNewWidth = 0;
        int lnNewHeight = 0;

        if (loBMP.Width < lnWidth && loBMP.Height < lnHeight)
            return loBMP;

        if (loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height)
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnWidth / loBMP.Width;
            lnNewWidth = lnWidth;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Height * lnRatio;
            lnNewHeight = (int)lnTemp;
        }

        else
        {
            lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
            lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
            decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
            lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
        }

        bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
        g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bmpOut;
}
```